# How to remove golang packages from CentOS

Tags: linux, go, centos, yum

How to remove golang packages from CentOS. I am unable to "yum remove golang" as it returns a no match error. How do I perform wildcard removal on CentOS to remove all the below packages

```
golang.x86_64                           1.6.3-2.el7                    base     
golang-bin.x86_64                       1.6.3-2.el7                    base     
golang-bitbucket-kardianos-osext-devel.noarch
golang-bitbucket-ww-goautoneg-devel.noarch
golang-bitbucket-ww-goautoneg-unit-test.x86_64
golang-cover.x86_64                     0-1.0.hgd32b5854c941.el7       epel     
golang-docs.noarch                      1.6.3-2.el7                    base     
golang-github-codegangsta-cli-devel.noarch
golang-github-coreos-go-log-devel.noarch
golang-github-coreos-go-systemd-devel.noarch
golang-github-cpuguy83-go-md2man.x86_64 1.0.4-2.el7_2                  base     
golang-github-cpuguy83-go-md2man-devel.noarch
golang-github-docopt-docopt-go-devel.noarch
golang-github-fsouza-go-dockerclient-devel.x86_64
golang-github-godbus-dbus-devel.noarch  0-0.1.gitcb98efb.el7.centos    extras   
golang-pkg-linux-386.noarch             1.4.2-1.el7.centos             extras   
golang-pkg-linux-amd64.noarch           1.4.2-1.el7.centos             extras   
golang-pkg-linux-arm.noarch             1.4.2-1.el7.centos             extras   
golang-pkg-netbsd-386.noarch            1.4.2-1.el7.centos             extras   
golang-pkg-netbsd-amd64.noarch          1.4.2-1.el7.centos             extras   
golang-pkg-netbsd-arm.noarch            1.4.2-1.el7.centos             extras   
golang-pkg-openbsd-386.noarch           1.4.2-1.el7.centos             extras   
golang-pkg-openbsd-amd64.noarch         1.4.2-1.el7.centos             extras   
golang-pkg-plan9-386.noarch             1.4.2-1.el7.centos             extras   
golang-pkg-plan9-amd64.noarch           1.4.2-1.el7.centos             extras   
golang-pkg-windows-386.noarch           1.4.2-1.el7.centos             extras   
golang-pkg-windows-amd64.noarch         1.4.2-1.el7.centos             extras   
golang-src.noarch                       1.6.3-2.el7                    base     
golang-tests.noarch                     1.6.3-2.el7                    base     
golang-vet.x86_64                       0-1.0.hgd32b5854c941.el7       epel     
golang-vim.noarch                       1.3.3-2.el7_0                  extras
```

Comment: Look [here](https://golang.org/doc/install#uninstall)

Comment: I think serverfault is a better place :)

Comment: You can't remove a package which isn't installed!

Answer (score 9):

Golang is currently only available in version 1.6.3 on CentOS. Therefore you should "install" it manually as described [here](https://golang.org/doc/install#install). I assume this is what you did and therefore, you will have to uninstall it manually as well.

**1. Remove the Go binary folder**

To find out where you installed Go, run

```
which go
```

which will return the location of the Go binary.

Next, remove the Go-Folder (as returned by the command above), for example:

```
[sudo] rm -rf /usr/local/go
```

**2. Remove extension of Environment varialbles**

Finally, you should remove the extension of environment variables. Usually this is done in one of the following files

```
/etc/profile
~/.profile
```

Remove any line that either sets the GOROOT or extends the PATH environment variable, so everything that looks like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export GOROOT=$HOME/go1.X
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

you can delete go directory by command "find",then install go use compile source code,finally set GOROOT and GOPATH in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove packages, you can enter the go source directory and remove the packages directory manually.

if you don't know where is your gopath, you can get it by type `go env` or `go env gopath`. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using a package manager to do.
You can use [Dep](https://golang.github.io/dep/) or [Go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything, because none of those packages are installed on your system.

You have listed *available* packages, not *installed* packages.

If the package was installed, a `@` symbol would appear next to the repository name in the third column. You could then remove it, and the `@` would disappear.